# Can not change p:dataTable row selection from PostFilterEvent

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, datatable

The goal is to automatically select the first row of the datatable when the user filters it. 
PostFilter event is implemented in order to select the first row but it happens it is actually overriden by whatever event happening afterwards and setting the initial selected row back.

```
<h:form id="customerForm">
    <p:commandButton value="selection change" action="#{customerControllerv1.selectionChange}"/> 
    <p:commandButton value="selection show" action="#{customerControllerv1.selectionShow}"/>
    <p:dataTable id="dtCustomer" var="customer" value="#{customerControllerv1.customers}" rowKey="#{customer.id}" 
        selection="#{customerControllerv1.selectedCustomer}" selectionMode="single" 
        binding="#{customerControllerv1.uiCustomers}">

        <f:event type="org.primefaces.event.data.PostFilterEvent" listener="#{customerControllerv1.postFilter()}" />

        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="First Name" filterBy="#{customer.firstName}" filterMatchMode="contains"  >
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.firstName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Last Name" filterBy="#{customer.lastName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.lastName}" /> 
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>    
</h:form>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name = "customerControllerv1")
@ViewScoped

public class CustomerControllerv1 implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Customer selectedCustomer;
    private DataTable uiCustomers;
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();   

    public CustomerControllerv1() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {        
        CustomerDAO custDAO = new CustomerDAO();
        customers = custDAO.getAllCustomers();         

        // select first row
        if (customers.size()>0) selectedCustomer=customers.get(0);
    }

   public void postFilter () {        
       selectionChange();
   }

   public void selectionChange () {
       RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
       List<Customer> sortedList = (List<Customer>)uiCustomers.getValue();
       // select first row of the filtered list and render the DataTable 
       if (sortedList.size()>0) selectedCustomer=sortedList.get(0);
       context.update("customerForm:dtCustomer");
   }

   public void selectionShow () {       
       System.out.println( "selectionShow: "+selectedCustomer.getId() );
   }


   // getters and setters
   ....
}
```

- selectionChange method is called by postFilter as well as from the button in the xhtml page. Clicking the selection change button selects the first row as expected. Clicking the selectionShow button will prove it.
- Entering data in the filter of the xhtml page also calls the same code but the first row selection is overidden afterwards. Clicking the selectionShow button will demonstrate it.

Does anybody have any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Seems to me like a bug, after the filtering the internal JavaScript Data of the p:dataTable still has the old selection (the variable `selection` of the dataTables widget war - you'll have to set one first). When you press the Button, primefaces sends this variable to the server, which changes the `selectedCustomer` in the Bean. Maybe selecting a row with the widget-var api would work, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I think this is a Primefaces wanted behaviour. The intent is probably to set the initial selection back when you remove the filter. But that's a behaviour I want to override.

Comment: There are a couple of methods in the Client Side API of p:dataTable like `selectRow`, see the documentation. I tried and it didn't work, maybe you'll find the solution.